# PHPExcel - format for the column

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I need to set for all columns format: FORMAT_NUMBER

I can do it for one cell. But I can not do for the whole column B.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

How to set the entire column B? 
PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat :: FORMAT_NUMBER

Comment: does it not work with just `getStyle('B')`? I know it works with styles, such as color and background.

Comment: Please note that, if it is [this repo](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that you're using, the master build fails and the develop build failed on errors. I would suggest you move to [the box/spout repo](https://github.com/box/spout). Had a quick look at the formatting options for you and `FORMAT_NUMBER` is not supported, unfortunately. However, it is more stable.

Comment: @Nukeface - debatable if it's more stable.... failing tests doesn't necessarily indicate instability

Answer (score 3):

You can set styling for an individual cell, or for a range of cells; but not for a column or a row.

To set the style for a range, use

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B2:B1024')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

So just identify the first and last rows that you want to set the style for in column `B`, and build a range string from that.

$column = 'B';
$firstRow = 2;
$lastRow = 1024;

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle($column.$firstRow.':'.$column.$lastRow)
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

Comment: And if I do not know the exact number of rows?

Comment: Then use `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();` or `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestDataRow();`, or keep track of the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (range('B', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataRow()) as $col) {
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$col)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
        }
```